# Python - print dict key from value within string order

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this following code:

```
d = {'one' : '11111111', 'two' : '01010101', 'three' : '10101010'}

string = '01010101 11111111 10101010'

text = ''

for key, value in d.items():
    if value in string:
        text += key
print(text)
```

output: onetwothree

however, my desired out put is the order of the string, so: twoonethree. Is this possible when using a dictionary in python? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing your dict(d) will help:

```
val2key = {value: key for key, value in d.items()}
text = "".join(val2key[value] for value in string.split())
print(text)
```

> twoonethree

Comment: Great! Would there also be away of doing this say the string had no whitespaces, eg: 010101011111111110101010

Comment: Yep, just replace **string.split()** with **textwrap.wrap(string, 8)**.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to split the string into a list and loop for every item in that list.

**EDIT:** The split() method returns a list of all words using a separator, in this case whitespace whitespace is used (You can call it as string.split() in case of whitespace by the way.)

```
dict = {'one' : '11111111', 'two' : '01010101', 'three' : '10101010'}

string = '01010101 11111111 10101010'

text = ''

for item in string.split(" "):
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if value == item:
            text += key + " "
print(text)
```

output: `two one three`